# how to separate single json file to pieces of json files

Tags: linux, python, perl, json, jq

We have the following `json` ( `example 1` )

**example 1**

```
more file.json

{
  "version": 1,
  "partitions": [
    {
      "topic": "list_of_cars",
      "partition": 2,
      "replicas": [
        1003,
        1004,
        1005
      ],
      "log_dirs": [
        "any",
        "any",
        "any"
      ]
    },
    {
      "topic": "list_of_cars",
      "partition": 4,
      "replicas": [
        1005,
        1006,
        1001
      ],
      "log_dirs": [
        "any",
        "any",
        "any"
      ]
    },
    {
      "topic": "list_of_cars",
      "partition": 0,
      "replicas": [
        1001,
        1002,
        1003
      ],
      "log_dirs": [
        "any",
        "any",
        "any"
      ]
    },
    {
      "topic": "list_of_cars",
      "partition": 1,
      "replicas": [
        1002,
        1003,
        1004
      ],
      "log_dirs": [
        "any",
        "any",
        "any"
      ]
    },
    {
      "topic": "list_of_cars",
      "partition": 5,
      "replicas": [
        1006,
        1001,
        1002
      ],
      "log_dirs": [
        "any",
        "any",
        "any"
      ]
    },
    {
      "topic": "list_of_cars",
      "partition": 3,
      "replicas": [
        1004,
        1005,
        1006
      ],
      "log_dirs": [
        "any",
        "any",
        "any"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

We want to cut each array from `topic` ( example 1 )

And redirect it to json files Pieces ( as `file1.json file2.json file3.json ..`  As the following  )

first file

```
more file1.json

{
    "version": 1,
     "partitions": [{
        "topic": "list_of_cars",
        "partition": 2,
        "replicas": [
               1003,
               1004,
               1005
                ],
                "log_dirs": [
                 "any",
                 "any",
                 "any"
       ]
   }]
}
```

second file

```
 more file2.json

{
    "version": 1,
     "partitions": [{
        "topic": "list_of_cars",
        "partition": 4,
        "replicas": [
               1005,
               1006,
               1001
                ],
                "log_dirs": [
                 "any",
                 "any",
                 "any"
       ]
   }]
}
```

third file

```
more file3.json
.
.
.
```

Comment: This question is a good argument for learning python.  The solution is a few lines of code.

Comment: can you show me please

Comment: Not only python, but javascript, perl and such

Comment: is it possible with bash?  , or jq?

Comment: Totally agree with @stolenmoment comment. Python is really the best language for this use case since, using `json` module, any json become a native python type. Then you just have to iterate over it and push the content into separate file.

Comment: @binarym let's not make this into a language popularity contest. Any scripting language with JSON support will do just as well, there's nothing special about Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `.partition[].partition` seems to hold the identifier for any particular partition, we can loop over these, and for each identifier delete the partitions that doesn't have that particular identifier.

The following assumes that the identifier is a simple integer with no spaces etc.:

```bash
for part in $(jq '.partitions[].partition' file.json); do
    jq --argjson part "$part" 'del(.partitions[] | select( .partition != $part ))' file.json >file-partition-"$part".json
done
```

This will create one file for each partition, named after the partition, not the index in the `.partition[]` array.

Comment: ( +1 ) for your effort , I will check that now